# How to catch the same exception for different functions efficiently?

Tags: exception, clojure

The following works in REPL, in case the database is down I get the map back.

```
(try
 (insert-table "db" "table" {:id 1 :text "text"}) 
 (catch Exception e {:err "can't connect to database"}))
```

I though I could write a function that takes a db operation and wrap it with a (try).

```
(defn catch-db-connection-errors
  [db_operation]
  (try
    (db_operation)
    (catch Exception e {:err "can't connect to database"})))
```

It does not catch the exception though. I might just overlook something very simple...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the form you pass in as an argument (e.g. `(insert-table "db" "table" {:id 1 :text "text"})`) is evaluated before the function is called, and the resulting value is passed into the function. To use another example, if you write `(println (+ 1 1))`, Clojure will first evaluate `(+ 1 1)` to get `2`, and then will call `(println 2)`. So if an exception is thrown in your DB code, it's before the catch-db-connection-errors function is called and thus outside the try form.

What you want is a macro, which thankfully is something Clojure is great at.

```
(defmacro catch-db-connection-errors [& db-operations]
  `(try
    ~@db-operations
    (catch Exception e {:err "can't connect to database"})))
```

This allows you to pass in however many database-handling forms you want and wraps them in your try-catch pair.

(Incidentally, you might want to catch something a little more specific than Exception, or else you could end up catching exceptions you don't intend do. But of course that's beside the point here.)

Comment: Thank you Chuck for the great explanation and for the macro as well. Yes, good point, actually I want to catch all of the exceptions related to the db-operations here, don't let it bubble up to higher layers. On the other side, I might just have few cases and change the returned string based on the actual exception type. Thank you again!